# A Simile for a Strenuous activity

Tags: word-choice, simile

Could anyone offer some similes for a strenuous activity.

The context is that:
you can have all sorts of great ideas at random times and random places but

"when you actually sit down and make an effort to come up with a good idea it’s more akin to [insert simile for something strenuous or difficult]"

Comment: trying to push a camel through the eye of a needle.

Comment: @Cynapse trying to find a penguin in the desert.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's effectively "creative writing advice" if we're specifically *not* being asked for set phrases/cliches.

Comment: I don't consider many of the answers cliche as they are not commonly used in my experience. However I understand your point. I will remove that stipulation from my question as it is a bit contradictory in a pure sense.

Comment: I just edited. Is that better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**nailing jelly to a tree**

> [like nailing jelly to a tree](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/like%20nailing%20jelly%20to%20a%20tree) *adj.*
>    Used to describe a task thought to be impossible, esp. one in which the difficulty arises from poor specification or inherent slipperiness in the problem domain.

- Also used in variant **“to a wall”**
- In AmE, **jello** or **Jell-O** is used instead of jelly.
- In BrE, jelly is used instead of jello.

---

**Bonus:**

Actually, some people even tried to nail jelly to a wall:

[image] [image]

<sub>Source: http://graeme.woaf.net/otherbits/jelly.html</sub>

It is like ideas slipping away...

---

These are related also:

> - getting blood from a stone (also get blood out of a stone)
> - catching/capturing lighting in a bottle
> - tough row to hoe
> - devil of a job (or devil's own job)

Answer (score 2):

*A one-legged man at an arse-kicking contest* - Rowan Atkinson

Answer (score 1):

Lighthearted?  [Self-menticide](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/menticide) -you did say lighthearted ;-)

Aprosexia [Inability to concentrate.](http://wiktionary.academic.ru/116340/aprosexia)

Comment: +1 for teaching me a new word lol... o wait i dont have enough rep to +1... :/

Comment: You need to get over your aprosexia -In other words: sh@t, or get off the pot

Answer (score 1):

**Like herding cats**, which got a segment on Mythbusters and was found to be significantly more difficult than the proverbial **like catching a greased pig**.  (That episode also tested the similar **like trying to put ten pounds of manure in a five pound bag**.  They do not test **herding rats with a blowdryer**.  I should also note there was a great cat-herding commercial during the Superbowl during the dotcom boom.)